# Can't seem to select element based on content

Tags: jquery, match

I'm trying to select an element based on its content, but I can't seem to get it working.

I have tried using regular expressions with `match()`:

```
$('.mod')
    .filter(function() {
    return this.match(/abc/);
 })
    .html("Test Worked!")
;
```

And `.text()`:

```
$('.mod')
    .filter(function() {
    return this.text() == 'abc' ;
 })
    .html("Test Worked")
;
```

But neither worked.

Am I doing something wrong?  I would prefer to use regular expressions, but right now I just want to select the element somehow.

Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/sethj/z3MBw/2/

Comment: `this` refers to the element node. It doesn't have a match method or a text method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

text() is a jQuery method :

```
$('div').filter(function() {
    return $(this).text().match(/mod/);
}).html("Matched!");
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/z3MBw/4/)

Answer (score 3):

Use this :

```
$('.mod')
  .filter(function() {
  return $(this).text() == 'abc' ;
})...
```

You can't call `text()` on a DOM element, you must wrap the element as a jQuery object.